# How can I make a Word 2010 heading begin a Normal paragraph when I hit Enter?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, styles

When I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing a heading, on my new computer it starts another heading in the same style. I want it to start a regular paragraph, not two headings in a row or a multiline heading. It seems like this is what the Style for Following Paragraph setting is for, but mine is set to "Normal" and it still doesn't go to Normal when I hit Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Some of MS Word's settings can be the cause of extreme frustration. Many users in our organisation end up just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times and then clicking a couple of rows above before applying the Heading style. That way they can just click (or down arrow) below and the paragraph style is fine.

However, one 'fix' I've found that sometimes gets this to work properly when defining the Heading 1 style is to make the Style for the following paragraph to be *Body Text*.

You could give that a try and see if it works for you. Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer, but for some reason I can no longer reproduce the problem. Have an upvote because I'm sure this will help.